# How to access searchBar's clear text button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, first-responder

When I hit the "clear" button *(the one that appears when editing)* on the tableView search, I was trying to get the keyboard to disappear.  How can I detect when the "clear" button is clicked, so I can resign the firstResponder?  **I already tried this in the `textDidChange` method:**

```
if (SearchBar.text == @"") {
    [SearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"clear called");
}
```

**which did not work...and also tried:**

```
 if (SearchBar.text == nil) {
    [SearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"clear called");
}
```

Neither methods show that they were called.  Any ideas?

**EDIT: Now resignFirstResponder does not seem to be working.  The keyboard stays on screen.  What's am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string comparison you should use

```
if([SearchBar.text isEqualToString: @""])
```

Comment: Yes it is in that method.  Thanks, this did the trick.  Now for some reason calling `resignFirstResponder` doesn't work.  Oh well. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try watching the `text` property of the search bar by registering for a KVO notification:

```
[self.searchBar addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

and then implementing:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  if (object == self.searchBar && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
    // Handle the new value of self.searchBar.text
  }
}
```

**Edit**: nevermind, answered above =)

Comment: Well, that would work, but it's a little more complicated than it needs to be for what my purposes are.  Thanks for trying to help, though!

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but another way to do this is:

`if(searchText.length == 0)`

in `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`

Comment: In fact this is probably the cleanest way to handle this, but I didn't know it at the time. Thanks for sharing.